# Retrieve XML WP7

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, tuples

I am wondering why when I retrive my XML i can't get any items from it .

So basically I use the phone to connect to my web service.

The XML returns a TUPLE of directory info and file info .

```
<TupleOfArrayOfDirectoryInfoArrayOfFileInfoe_PmhuPqo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <m_Item1 xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO">
<a:DirectoryInfo>
<OriginalPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">AETN</OriginalPath>
<FullPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"              i:type="b:string">C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Files\TEST1</FullPath>
 </a:DirectoryInfo>
 <a:DirectoryInfo>
<OriginalPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">BT</OriginalPath>
<FullPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     i:type="b:string">C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Files\TEST2</FullPath>
</a:DirectoryInfo>
  <a:DirectoryInfo>
<OriginalPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">Comixology</OriginalPath>
<FullPath xmlns="" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   i:type="b:string">C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Files\TEST3</FullPath>
</a:DirectoryInfo>
```

On my code on windows phone 7 application,I am using this piece of code after I download the xml from the right url :

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Error == null) 
        { 
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None); 
            var folders = from query in xdoc.Descendants("DirectoryInfo") 
                          select new Folder 
                          { 
                              Name = (string)query.Element("OriginalPath"), 
                          }; 
            listBox2.ItemsSource = folders; 
        } 
    }
```

I get this error :

```
'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your solution already? It seems there might be a problem with the references. Also, at which line does the error get thrown?

Comment: There are no errors thrown. It's just NAME wich is an empty string .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your question you state you get an error about a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the error, but the problem with no elements returned is because you have a namespace applied on the `DirectoryInfo` elements, so you have to search using it:

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Error == null) 
    { 
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

        XNamespace aNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO");

        var folders = from query in xdoc.Descendants(aNamespace.GetName("DirectoryInfo")) 
                      select new Folder 
                      { 
                          Name = (string)query.Element("OriginalPath"), 
                      }; 
        listBox2.ItemsSource = folders; 
    } 
}
```